# Flask object with the same lifetime as application

Tags: python, flask, neo4j

---

I am trying to build a REST API using Flask, and Neo4j. Using the official Python driver for Neo4j, it seems that I need to have a driver object that can be used to get database connections when needed.

Is there any way I can store an object in Flask that lives as long as the application is running? I am aware of the application context wherein you can pass data, but if what I understand is correct, the application context is popped from the stack for each request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by writing your own flask extension. The [example](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/extensiondev/) shows how to make a connection with SQLite, but you can easily adapt it for neo4j.

Comment: I've seen a Flask extension using Neo4j, but upon reading the code, it is creating a driver for every request which would take a lot of time. I might be wrong but it seems that extensions are for modifying the application context stack...

Comment: Extensions are for everything that Flask itself does not do. Another option is to create a subclass of `Flask`, but, writing *your own* extension is more preferable. Yet another option is to fork existing extension and fix the problem you had pointed out.